# How do I write an asynchronous Map function in Javascript from scratch?

Tags: javascript, node.js, dictionary, asynchronous, functional-programming

I need help writing this asyncMap function from scratch. I think I've almost got it, but I'm not sure why I keep getting the wrong answer. Here's the code I have so far:

```
function wait3For1(callback){
    setTimeout(function(){
        callback('one')
    }, 300)
}

function wait2For5(callback){
    setTimeout(function(){
        callback('five')
    }, 200)
}


function asyncMap(tasks, callback){
    return callback(
    tasks.map((item) => 
        item((element) => element)))
}

asyncMap([wait3For1, wait2For5], function(arr){
    console.log(arr) //expect ['one', 'five']
});
```

I keep getting     `[undefined, undefined]`
I'm pretty sure it's because I'm not doing the callbacks wait2For5 and wait3For1 correctly, but not sure what the problem is.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: This is a perfect use case for promises which have far better error catching than using callbacks

Comment: Is your asyncMap suppose to do things in parallel or in sequence?  In other words, can all async operations be in flight at the same time or do you expect them to execute one after the other?

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that you're not waiting for the results to come back, collecting them, and then sending them back via the callback. See if this code helps. (It works when tested with your program.)

```
function asyncMap(tasks, callback) {
    // array to collect the results
    let results = [];

    // count of how many results we're waiting for
    let remaining = tasks.length;

    tasks.forEach((task, i) => {
        task((result) => {
            // Store the result in the right position.
            results[i] = result;

            // See how many results we're still waiting for.
            remaining -= 1;

            // If we're done, invoke the callback.
            if (remaining === 0) {
                callback(results);
            }
        });
    });
}
```

Comment: function should be called something other than `asyncMap` if it's not going to take a mapping function.

Answer (score 0):

You are basically creating  poor man's promise but without any error handling capability.

Try

```js
   function waitFor(val, dur){
       return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {       
        setTimeout(function() {
          resolve(val)
        }, dur);
      });    
    }

    
    Promise.all([waitFor('one',600), waitFor('five', 100)]).then( function(arr) {
      console.log(arr) //expect ['one', 'five']
    }).catch(function(err){
      console.log('ooops error:' , err)
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

In your code, you're using the synchronous `Array.prototype.map`

```
function asyncMap(tasks, callback){
    return callback(
    tasks.map((item) => 
        item((element) => element)))
}
```

Since `wait3For1` and `wait2For5` have no `return`, they will implicitly return `undefined` which will be used in the result of the `.map` call. Obviously we will want to wait for the callback to be called before assigning the mapped value to the final result.

The other issue is that *mapping* over an array uses a *function* — `map(items)` doesn't really make sense without a function to map the items with. So we'll address that in the solution below as well.

It will help if you start with `asyncReduce` and then implement `asyncMap` as an async reduce. Note, the code below will process the items in a series. If you wish for the items to be processed in parallel, a slightly different approach would be required. Let me know in the comments and I'll be happy to write up another variant.

```js
function wait3For1(callback){
  setTimeout(function(){
    callback('one')
  }, 300)
}

function wait2For5(callback){
  setTimeout(function(){
    callback('five')
  }, 200)
}

function asyncReduce(xs, f, initial, callback) {
  if (xs.length === 0)
    callback(null, initial)
  else
    f(initial, xs[0], function(x) {
      asyncReduce(xs.slice(1), f, x, callback)
    })
}

function asyncMap(xs, f, callback) {
  asyncReduce(xs, function(acc, x, k) {
    f(x, function(y) { k(acc.concat([y])) })
  }, [], callback)
}

asyncMap([wait3For1, wait2For5], function(f,callback) {
  f(callback)
}, function(err, arr) {
  console.log(arr) //=> ['one', 'five']
})
```

Go ahead and run the code snippet to see it work

---

I see you using some arrow functions so you probably have a somewhat recent version of node. Here's the exact same thing but using ES6 instead

```js
// ES6
const wait3For1 = callback=>
  setTimeout(callback, 300, 'one')

const wait2For5 = callback=>
  setTimeout(callback, 200, 'five')

const asyncReduce = ([x,...xs], f, initial, callback) =>
  x === undefined
    ? callback(null, initial)
    : f(initial, x, y=> asyncReduce(xs, f, y, callback))

const asyncMap = (xs, f, callback)=>
  asyncReduce(xs, (acc, x, k)=>
    f(x, y=> k([...acc, y]))
  , [], callback)

asyncMap(
  [wait3For1, wait2For5],
  (f, callback)=> f(callback),
  (err, arr)=> console.log(arr) // ['one', 'five']
)
```

---

Crafting higher order functions from scratch is a very valuable exercise, but as another answer points out, you're just implementing a "poor man's `Promise.all`", but much less versatile. You should convert `wait3For1` and `wait2For5` to Promise creators and use `Promise.all` instead.

Your next question might be how to implement `Promise.all`... I've done this recent and found it to be quite a fun challenge. I hope some of the techniques shared in this answer will help should you choose to explore an implementation from scratch ^_^